# .dSYM folder for debugging

Tags: c, xcode, debugging, gcc, gnu

I just set-up `GNU gcc` on my Mac through some re-organization of my path and builds so it's not an alias for clang anymore. Running `gcc -g`, I expect debugging symbols to be self-contained within the executable, but they are still generating the `.dSYM`. How can I get the behavior I expect instead of the `.dSYM` folder, which I believe comes from Xcode command line tools?

I am specifically running:

`gcc -O3 -g3 -Wall -Wextra -fanalyzer -march=native -mtune=native -mrdrnd`

but this behavior even occurs with basic `gcc -g hello.c -o hello_world` program.

Comment: What is the size of your executable with and without `-g`?

Comment: Not too familar with macOS, but from: https://www.iosiqa.com/2020/03/dsym-file-firebase-crashlytics.html we have: _A dSYM file is "debug symbol file". It is generated when "strip debug symbols" setting is enabled in build setting._ This appears to be the default. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/84942 So, not so dependent upon which compiler is used.

Comment: Under linux, there is `dsymutil` which may be helpful.

Comment: the difference for a basic `hello.c` program I compile on a remote machine (that does not have this issue) running Red Hat Linux is about 1kb. even a `hello.c` compilation gets the `.dSYM` folder on my Mac @stark

Comment: @CraigEstey i see, the issue is that there is no `build setting` that I know of. I didn't even realize that Xcode was involved in what i'm doing, since it is purely command line and not through Xcode